# Initialize nested struct definition in Golang if it have same objects

Tags: json, go, struct

I have struct like this:

> ```
> type AutoGenerated struct {
>  Accounting []struct {
>     FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
>     LastName string `json:"lastName"`
>     Age int `json:"age"`
> } `json:"accounting"`
> Sales []struct {
>     FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
>     LastName string `json:"lastName"`
>     Age int `json:"age"`
> } `json:"sales"`
> ```
>
> }

I want to assign values to it like this:-

```
data := AutoGenerated{}
data.Accounting.LastName = "Apple2"
data.Accounting.FirstName = "Apple1"
data.Accounting.Age = 20
data.Sales.LastName = "Ball2"
data.Sales.FirstName = "Ball1"
data.Sales.Age = 30
```

But is is giving error which is **data.Accounting.LastName undefined**

*Although same code is working fine for*

> ```
> type AutoGenerated struct {
>     FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
>     LastName string `json:"lastName"`
>     Age int `json:"age"`
> }
> ```

Where I assigned the values like this:-

```
data := AutoGenerated{}
data.LastName = "Apple2"
data.FirstName = "Apple1"
data.Age = 20
```

Please don't assign values manually I have to take values from other function.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner structs are slices. Either use this:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
 Accounting struct {
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName string `json:"lastName"`
    Age int `json:"age"`
} `json:"accounting"`
Sales struct {
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName string `json:"lastName"`
    Age int `json:"age"`
} `json:"sales"`
```

Or if you need to have more than one Sale or Accounting per struct then you have to initialize the slices and refer to them by index.

Answer (score 0):

In your object `data` of `AutoGenerated` type, `data.Accounting` is a slice of structs. Before you can use `data.Accounting` slice, you'll need to initialize it. An example usage would be:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
 Accounting []Account `json:"accounting"`
 Sales []struct {
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName string `json:"lastName"`
    Age int `json:"age"`
 } `json:"sales"`
}

// defined separately for better readability
type Account struct {
    FirstName string `json:"firstName"`
    LastName string `json:"lastName"`
    Age int `json:"age"`
}
```

Then to assign values to the struct:

```
a := AutoGenerated{}
a.Accounting = make([]Account, 1) // create the slice of appropriate length
// append values to it
a.Accounting = append(a.Accounting, Account{"firstname", "lastname", 30})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.
    `a := AutoGenerated{}
     a.Accounting = make([]Account, 0)
     a.Accounting = append(a.Accounting, Account{"ACfirst", "AClast", 30})
     a.Sales = make([]Sale, 0)
     a.Sales = append(a.Sales, Sale{"slefirst", "slelast", 20})`