# Golang: Protobuff generated Struct is not decoding child attribute for json.Unmarshling

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have one struct which is getting used with protobuff serialiser and works well.

This struct is generated by protobuff hence it has so many methods like Unmarshal etc.

```
type Flight struct {
    FlightNo string  `json:"flightno, omitempty"`
    Carrier string   `json:"carrier, omitempty"`
}
func (m *Flight) Unmarshal(data []byte) error {
    l := len(data)
    iNdEx := 0
    for iNdEx < l {
        preIndex := iNdEx
        var wire uint64
        for shift := uint(0); ; shift += 7 {
            if shift >= 64 {
                return ErrIntOverflowFlight
            }
            if iNdEx >= l {
                return io.ErrUnexpectedEOF
            }
            b := data[iNdEx]
            iNdEx++
            wire |= (uint64(b) & 0x7F) << shift
            if b < 0x80 {
                break
            }
        }
    }
 // some more code
}
```

Then I want to add additional field to this flight info,

```
type FlightMeta struct {
    Source string `json:"source, omitempty"`
    Destination string `json:"destination, omitempty"`
}
```

Then i have combined struct of these two,

```
type CombinedFlight struct {
    Flight
    FlightMeta

}

type ResponseFlight struct {
    OnwardFlights  []CombinedFlight  `json:"onwardflights, omitempty"`
    ReturnFlights  []CombinedFlight  `json:"returnflights, omitempty"`
    Error string  `json:"error, omitempty"`
}
```

So when i read some data like,

```
str "= `{"onwardflights": [{"flightno": "537", "carrier": "AI", "source": "BOM", "destination": "DEL"}], "error": "false"}`
respFlight = new(ResponseFlight)

err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &respFlight)

fmt.Println("flightno:", respFlight.OnwardFlights[0].FlightNo, "flight source", respFlight.OnwardFlights[0].Source)

#prints "flightno:537 flight source:
```

It doesn't print value for second struct, as per methis is not unmarshling properly.

But when i set the attribute manually and marshal(encode it to json) this is working fine.
Any leads.?

Comment: [The code in the question works as expected in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bXMCYqNq8A).

Comment: Thanks @MellowMarmot. I didn't post further struct methods like reset and someother things in diffrent module. Can such lines make any difference ?

Comment: Please post a [complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code as posted works. It's difficult to guess what's wrong with the code that we cannot see.

Comment: You may be tripped up by thinking of this as inheritance. There is absolutely no inheritance going on here, just composition. A selector expression will automatically find the proper field or method to delegate to when there's no ambiguity, but `CombinedFlight` itself is not a `Flight` or a `FlghtMeta`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
        type CombinedFlight1 struct {
            Flight
            FlightMeta

        }


        type CombinedFlight2 struct {
            Flight
            FlightMeta

        }

        type ResponseFlight struct {
           OnwardFlights  []CombinedFlight1  `json:"onwardflights, omitempty"`
           ReturnFlights  []CombinedFlight2  `json:"returnflights, omitempty"`
           Error string  `json:"error, omitempty"`
        }
```

It will work fine and if you want to marshal, you have to create two different structure. For more understanding see this post

Visit [Initialize nested struct definition in Golang if it have same objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501646/initialize-nested-struct-definition-in-golang-if-it-have-same-objects)

Comment: This works like the code in the question. What's the advantage of using different types for the slice elements? The linked post does not address this.